# Insert SQL запрос с join в returning

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Сам запрос:

```
insert into products_ref(name, fullname, barcode, vat_rate, comment, group_id, base_measure_unit_id, manufacturer_id, iscommission, isdeleted, created_at, created_by, updated_at, updated_by, packing_size, packing_measure_unit_id) 
values('Замиокулькас', 'Замиокулькас великолепный', '800700', 0.200000, 'пейте охлаждённым!', 3, 3, 2, true, false, now(), 13, now(), 13, 0.000000, 3) 
returning p.id AS product_id,p.sku as product_sku, p.name as product_name, p.fullname as product_fullname, p.barcode as product_barcode, p.vat_rate as product_vat_rate, p.comment as product_comment, p.group_id as product_group_id, g.name as group_name, g.parent_id as group_parent_id, p.base_measure_unit_id as product_measure_unit_id, m.name as measure_name, m.fullname as measure_fullname, m.code as measure_code, p.manufacturer_id as product_manufacturer_id, mfc.name as manufacturer_name, mfc.inn as manufacturer_inn, mfc.phone as manufacturer_phone, p.iscommission as product_iscommission, to_char(p.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text) AS product_created_at, p.created_by as product_created_by,to_char(p.updated_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text) AS product_updated_at, p.updated_by as product_updated_by,p.packing_size as product_packing_size, p.packing_measure_unit_id as product_packing_measure_unit_id, m1.name as packing_measure_name, m1.fullname as packing_measure_fullname, m1.code as packing_measure_code 
FROM products_ref as p 
JOIN products_groups_ref as g on g.id = p.group_id 
JOIN products_measure_units_ref as m ON m.id = p.base_measure_unit_id 
JOIN products_measure_units_ref as m1 ON m1.id = p.packing_measure_unit_id 
JOIN products_manufacturers_ref as mfc ON mfc.id = p.manufacturer_id
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 4: FROM products_ref as p 
        ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 1410
```

Использую субд postgresql. Все таблицы и столбцы в запросе существуют. Как правильно построить такой запрос?

Comment: Можете через `WITH` это сделать попробовать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59232417/8324991 А вообще какой-то монструозный запрос, странно выглядит

Comment: RETURNING - это последняя кляуза запроса, после неё никакого FROM быть не может.